# Image from flask to javascript using ajax

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, flask, flask-restful

I have the need to send images from python script to the javascript file. I am using Flask to communicate between 2 scripts. I have tried to convert the image matrix to string and sending it that way. But It seems very messy, as invisible characters get added etc.

Is there any other way I can get hold of the image (in matrix form) in my js file?

Thanks

Comment: not 100% sure what you're looking for based on the info provided. you might want to  look into base64 encoding for string based image formatting/storage/retrieval. otherwise post code for further evaluation.

Comment: Basically yeah, I am using OpenCV in python to capture video frame then I want to pass it along to javascript for pose detection to obtain body joints keypoints dict. Then I wanted to send the dict back to python for processing agian.